# Facebook iOS SDK - in-app auth dialog terms/privacy policy links lead to dead end

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have my Facebook iOS SDK set up so that if the Facebook app is not present it will display an auth dialog within the app (instead of switching to Safari). That is, in the SDK's Facebook.m file I changed to:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:NO];
```

It's working great except for one thing: all of Facebook's app auth dialogs include external links to the app's Terms and Privacy Policy at the bottom. Given the setup described, if you click one of these links, they open within the in-app dialog and thus you reach a dead end: there's no back button or other way to get back to the auth dialog.

Surely this is a bug within the SDK? Is there a good way to hack more appropriate handling of these links either "externally" or within the SDK code?